# VUE get item from table after click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm using vue bootstrap and i would like to receive item from click row in table.

I've created table and clickmeRow method to do something with click item.

```
<b-table-lite 
        hover
        :items="items"
        @row-clicked="clickmeRow(item)"
    />
```

and the method is:

```
clickmeRow(item) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

When i click, in console i have: undefined

Could you please help me to retreive item from table after click?

Answer (score 0):

The reason isn't `undefined` is because you're writing calling the function inside the template with the `item` variable, which is undefined.
The item is passed to the method by default, so you only need to write `@row-clicked="clickmeRow"`

Reference: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-lite-events

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald'
        },
        {
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw'
        },
        {
          age: 89,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson'
        },
        {
          age: 38,
          first_name: 'Jami',
          last_name: 'Carney'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onRowClicked(item, index, event) {
      console.log("Index", index)
      console.log("Item", item);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <b-table-lite :items="items" @row-clicked="onRowClicked"></b-table-lite>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, index is ok, but the 'item' is: {__ob__: Observer}, how to get from it the item name?

Comment: That *is* the item object, it's just showing you the observer when collapsed. If you click the little `arrow` in your console to expand the object, then you should see the properties of the item object. Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ekU4bys.png)

Comment: Ok, but what if i just want to have displayed in console first_name if i click first_name in row?

Comment: `console.log(item.first_name)`? Not sure I fully understand the question.